# Sitecore CM container unhealthy after adding new volume

Tags: unicorn, docker

I have created a blank project using https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html

Added a new volume to CM to sync Unicorn items as per in docker-compose-override.yml as per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FYapLQOLEo&t=815s

So the updated cm service looks like this:

```
cm:
    image: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xp0-cm:${VERSION:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./docker/build/cm
      args:
        PARENT_IMAGE: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp0-cm:${SITECORE_VERSION}
        SOLUTION_IMAGE: ${REGISTRY}${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-solution:${VERSION:-latest}
        TOOLS_IMAGE: ${TOOLS_IMAGE}
        MANAGEMENT_SERVICES_IMAGE: ${MANAGEMENT_SERVICES_IMAGE}
        HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE: ${HEADLESS_SERVICES_IMAGE}
    depends_on:
      - solution
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_DEPLOY_PATH}\platform:C:\deploy      
      - ${LOCAL_DATA_PATH}\cm:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs
      **- ${LOCAL_ITEM_PATH}\serialization:C:\serialization**
      - ${HOST_LICENSE_FOLDER}:c:\license      
    environment:
      SITECORE_LICENSE_LOCATION: c:\license\license.xml
      RENDERING_HOST_PUBLIC_URI: "https://${RENDERING_HOST}"
      ## Development Environment Optimizations
      SITECORE_DEVELOPMENT_PATCHES: DevEnvOn,CustomErrorsOff,DebugOn,DiagnosticsOff,InitMessagesOff,RobotDetectionOff
      Sitecore_AppSettings_exmEnabled:define: "no" # remove to turn on EXM
    entrypoint: powershell.exe -Command "& C:\tools\entrypoints\iis\Development.ps1"
```

This results in a unhealthy CM container. If the new volume is removed, the container is healthy.

Can someone help as to why there is an issue and how I can introduce a new volume for syncing serialized items.

Comment: Do you have `LOCAL_ITEM_PATH` defined in `.env` file? Does it exist on your laptop? Does it contain `serialization` folder?

Comment: The container was unhealthy as the sql login failed each time after running init.ps1. The solution is to run clean.ps1 or clean up the databases in docker\data\sql

Comment: This helped identify the cause of the problem: https://visionsincode.com/2021/01/09/curl-your-way-out-when-404-page-not-found-in-your-sitecore-docker-setup/ and here is the fix https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27954/unknown-connection-string-name-1-unicorn